# Rails using Rspec to test ---> ActionView::MissingTemplate:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I am trying to test something very simple with Rsec on my Rails app.

This is the test piece of code in spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb

```
 describe MoviesController do
   describe 'update' do                                                        
      it 'should call the model method to look up the movie to update' do                                          
        Movie.should_receive(:find).with("3")         
        put :update, {:id => "3"}                                             
     end
   end
```

This is the controller method in controllers/movies_controller.rb:

```
def update
   Movie.find(params[:id])
end
```

And I get this problem:

```
1) MoviesController update should call the model method to look up the movie to update Failure/Error: post :update, {:id => "3"} ActionView::MissingTemplate: Missing template movies/update, application/update with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "#<RSpec::Rails::ViewRendering::EmptyTemplatePathSetDecorator:0xa65b300>" # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My routes look like:

```
    movies GET    /movies(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"movies"}
           POST   /movies(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"movies"}
 new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"movies"}
edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}
     movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies"}
           PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"movies"}
           DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"movies"}
```

Could anyone please help me and tell me what the hell I am doing wrong in such a simple example?

Comment: Try putting in a redirect_to movie_path at the end of the update so it doesn't try to look for movies/update

Comment: Got a similar problem in one project, the worst part is that it doesn't show up when calling rspec on a single spec file!

Answer (score 10):

According to [the doc](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-8/docs/controller-specs/views-are-stubbed-by-default), the template must exist when you test your controller since `views are stubbed by default`.

So your controller may be clean, but the rendering file must exist (even if it doesn't compile).

Answer (score -1):

Since you do not have a redirect in your update action, rails is going to use the default convention for what view to render so it's going to try and use 'app/views/movies/update.html.erb' to render the view which you probably don't have. Typically after an update you want to redirect to  a show type view. Check out what a typical update action looks like here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#editing-posts